# MySQL for joining a table on uuid and omitting uuids present in both table

Tags: mysql, anti-join

I'm trying to figure out **how best to write a statement** that omits returning rows (`maintable`) that a user (`uuid_user`) has already seen (`seentable`). Rows that a user has already seen are stored in `seentable`. Here is a simplified version of my tables. `uuid` is used as the key to join. `uuid_user` identifies the particular user's seen rows.

Not quite working:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM maintable 
  JOIN seentable 
    on maintable.uuid = seentable.uuid 
 WHERE maintable.uuid != seentable.uuid
```

```
maintable
uuid (char36)
lng,lat (POINT)
timestamp (timestamp)

seentable 
uuid (char36)
uuid_user (char36)
timestamp (timestamp)
```

Comment: 'Improved'? As in to move from 'not working' to 'working'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to stick with a join approach, then you can use a left anti-join:

```sql
SELECT m.*
FROM maintable m
LEFT JOIN seentable s ON m.uuid = s.uuid
WHERE s.uuid IS NULL;
```

Or, you could phrase this using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT m.*
FROM maintable m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM seentable s WHERE s.uuid = m.uuid);
```

Comment: interesting, did not know there is sucha thing as an anti-join!

Comment: Ah, actually this doesn't quite work - since if a user hasn't seen a particular row from maintable, it won't be in seentable. (sorry updated the table to include uuid_user in seentable)

Comment: Or should I have a new "seen" table of for each user?

Comment: I have reverted your question, and you should ask a new one.  If you really feel the need to edit this way, you should at least include sample data, which you did not do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309124/mysql-omitting-rows-a-user-has-already-seen-from-checking-a-seen-table