# MySQL omitting rows a user has already seen from checking a "seen" table

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, anti-join

I'm trying to figure out **how best to write a statement** that omits returning rows (`maintable`) that a user (`uuid_user`) has already seen (`seentable`).

- Q: Should I have the "seen" table be a separate table for each user?

**Currently, I have it as a single `seen` table for all users**

Rows that a user has already seen are stored in `seentable` for each `uuid_user`. Here is a simplified version of my tables. `uuid` is used as the key to join. `uuid_user` identifies the particular user's seen rows.

Not quite working:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM maintable m 
 LEFT JOIN seentable s 
    on m.uuid = s.uuid 
 WHERE s.uuid IS NULL and s.uuid_user = '[user]'
```

```
maintable
uuid (char36)
lng,lat (POINT)
timestamp (timestamp)

seentable 
uuid (char36)
uuid_user (char36)
timestamp (timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the restriction on `uuid_user` from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM maintable m 
LEFT JOIN seentable s 
    ON m.uuid = s.uuid AND s.uuid_user = '[user]'
WHERE s.uuid IS NULL;
```

The above is the logic you want here.  Now, a successful join between records from the two tables occurs whenever the `uuid` values match *and* when the `uuid_user` value from the seen table matches some value.  Note that should the `uuid_user` value *not* match for any record, it would not be filtered off, which is what will happen with your current query.